# Merge two columns into one column, one cell after another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, merge

I am trying to merge two columns into one column, one cell after another. For example, I have start time in one column and End time into another column, shown in pic. I am trying to merge them into one column (Time) that has start time in one cell and end time in the cell just below it, with duplicating the code (the third column) with each addition. Like shown in the pic.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Use INDEX, MOD, and ROW.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You need to show some mocked up data and expected output not just headers.

Comment: @ScottCraner just updated!

Comment: Do the start time and End Time of other rows overlap or are they always sequential, and on what part of the time should it iterate, Hour, Minute, Second?

Comment: Or do you just want two rows for every one,one for the start time and one for the end time?

Comment: @ScottCraner they are always sequential. Usually seconds.

Comment: yes, two rows for every one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Forwards:***

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$9,ROUND(ROW(A1)/2,0),MOD(ROW(),2)+1)
```

Formula in `E2`:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,ROUND(ROW(A1)/2,0))
```

---

***Backwards:***

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$9,ROUND(((COUNTA(C:C)-1)*2-(ROW(A1)-1))/2,0),MOD(ROW(A1),2)+1)
```

Formula in `E2`:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,ROUND(((COUNTA(C:C)-1)*2-(ROW(A1)-1))/2,0))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you explain what you did here? I'm also getting the time from end to start instead of start to end.

Comment: @AmalHope, I'm merely using some (`ROUND`, `ROW` and `MOD`) to return the values for the second and third parameter of the `INDEX` function. If you read about `INDEX` you'll see it takes a row and column parameter. Best is to step through the formula using the build-in Evaluate Formula function.

Comment: @amalhope, included an idea for backwards iterations (which surely can be simplified a bit)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is the forumula I would use:

```
=CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,2),INDEX(A1:B8,(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0)-MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0),COLUMNS(A1:B8)))/COLUMNS(A1:B8)+1,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0),COLUMNS(A1:B8))+1),INDEX(C1:C8,(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0)-MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0),COLUMNS(A1:B8)))/COLUMNS(A1:B8)+1))
```

But that formula is a bit messy, so, I wrote another one that breaks down the formula in a way that I can talk through how it works and what its doing:

```
=LET(
     TimeRange,A1:B8,
     CodeRange,C1:C8,

     RowCount,ROWS(TimeRange),
     ColumnCount,COLUMNS(TimeRange),
     CellCount,RowCount*ColumnCount,

     BaseSequence,SEQUENCE(CellCount,,0),
     ModSequence,MOD(BaseSequence,ColumnCount),
     RowIndex,(BaseSequence-ModSequence)/ColumnCount+1,
     ColumnIndex,ModSequence+1,

     Result1,
     INDEX(TimeRange,RowIndex,ColumnIndex),
     Result2,
     INDEX(CodeRange,RowIndex),
     CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,2),Result1,Result2)
)
```

If you want to paste this formula into your spreadsheet, just make sure that you have the formula bar selected. If you don't, Excel will paste the text so that each line break moves to the next row.

What does each part do? This table steps through each parameter, and explains what each one does. And yes, when using a `LET` statement, you can use variable names declared in the prior step, but you can't do it the other way!

| Part | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `LET(` | `LET` basically allows us to name our own variables. You'll see what I mean in the following sections |
| TimeRange, B11# | This is the StartTime and EndTime Ranges from your example |
| CodeRange, D11# | This is the Code range from your example |
| RowCount, ROWS(TimeRange) | This gives us the number of rows in TimeRange, and stores it as RowCount |
| ColumnCount, COLUMNS(TimeRange) | This gives us the number of columns in TimeRange, and stores it as RowCount |
| CellCount, RowCount*ColumnCount | This calculates how many cells there are. Note that our answer will have rows equal to CellCount |
| BaseSequence, SEQUENCE(CellCount,,0) | This creates a sequence of numbers, arranged in a single column, starting at 0, and stores the result in BaseSequence |
| ModSequence, MOD(BaseSequence, ColumnCount) | Here, we take the `MOD` of BaseSequence, by ColumnCount. Why? Because this effectively gives us a list of numbers counting up from 0 to 1. Note that this is why BaseSequence had to start at 0 |
| RowIndex, (BaseSequence - ModSequence)/ColumnCount + 1 | This basically counts through the rows, giving us 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, (etc) |
| ColumnIndex, ModSequence + 1 | Because unlike `MOD`, which starts at 0, column and row indices start at 1 |
| Result1, INDEX(TimeRange, RowIndex, ColumnIndex) | This is our left hand column, and basically picks through the TimeRange, going through each row by picking up each column first |
| Result2, INDEX(CodeRange, RowIndex) | This is our right hand column, and it basically doubles up each element in the CodeRange (i.e. teacher, teacher, student, etc), because RowIndex runs 1, 1, 2, 2, 3… |
| CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,2),Result1, Result2) | The last item in a LET statement is the one that returns a value to the spreadsheet. Here, I'm using a `SEQUENCE` to make a range 1 row and ColumnCount columns wide (i.e. [1, 2]). This goes into `CHOOSE`, which will select Result1 when it gets a 1, and Result2 when it gets a 2. Because both Result1 and Result2 are ranges, `CHOOSE` effectively combines them into a single Range |

Also, in the event you want it, this is the formula I posted first (at the top), but with additional line breaks to improve legibility:

```
=CHOOSE(
     SEQUENCE(,2),
     INDEX(
          A1:B8,
          (
               SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0)
               -MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0),COLUMNS(A1:B8))
          )
          /COLUMNS(A1:B8)+1,
          MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0),COLUMNS(A1:B8))+1
     ),
     INDEX(
          C1:C8,
          (
               SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0)
               -MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B8)*COLUMNS(A1:B8),,0),COLUMNS(A1:B8))
          )
          /COLUMNS(A1:B8)+1
     )
)
```